# Git merge keep mv history

Tags: git, merge, move

I have recently made a big change to folder structure in a branch using `git mv` resulting in no Added/Removed files only Renames in order to keep history.

Merging this branch to other branches result in Add/Remove on all files with content changes.

Git obviously understands the files moved since it tries to perform the Remove/Add.

How can I make sure that the history of my files stays intact during merges with renamed files?

Answer (score 0):

Git does not actually track renames, but infers them heuristically by determining how much removed files and added files match.  There are some config (and command line options) that can aid the detection:

```
[diff]
    renamelimit = 3000
```

Which you can set via `git config --global diff.renameLimit 3000`.  There is also a `merge.renameLimit`, but if it's unset, it defaults to `diff.renameLimit`.  Unfortunately, I can't find any documented default value, but the [source code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/diff.c#L32) seems to indicate that 400 is the default limit.

Or you can look at the `-l` option to `git diff` as well as the `-M`/`--find-renames` option.